# One to many relationship in mysql

Tags: mysql

I Have the two tables `User` and `Assets`. The situation is as followed :

- 1 assets to several users.

What should be my Database design ?

User

```
+---------+---------+
| UserId | Name     |
+---------+---------+
```

Assets

```
+---------+---------+
| AssetId | Name    |
+---------+---------+
```

User_asset_relation

```
+---------+---------+
| UserId  | AssetId |
+---------+---------+
```

What I think is that `UserId` and `AssetId` should have another table with foreign keys from the other two tables.

Comment: Can 1 user have multiple assets ? If yes you shoudl create many to many or  one  to many

Comment: Yes , 1 user may have multiple assets

Comment: my suggestion would be that you create another table like user_asset_relation
with 1 id which is auto increment for the primary key and the two primary keys from the other tables should be the foreign keys of user_asset_relation.

Comment: Hmm yes that i have designed , but junction table no. Of row Will be too large .

Comment: What do you mean with table no. Of row?

Comment: You many to many should be something like this CREATE TABLE user_assets_relation (
    Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    UserId int NOT NULL,
    AssetId int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES User(UserId),
    FOREIGN KEY (AssetId) REFERENCES Assets(AssetId)
);

Answer (score -1):

The design you described is actually many to many relationship. If each user is assigned only one asset, than you can add assetId column to users table.
If one user can have multiple assets and same asset can be assigned to multiple users, than this is many to many relationship and your design is ok.

Comment: I think my 1 asset is assigned to many user so i thought it is one to many.

Comment: You're definitely correct. You have described a one to many relationship. Sorry I can't help design input but at first glance it looks effective.